# Класс-итератор c++

Tags: c++, итераторы

Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть класс для хранения двусвязного списка (аналог std::list), мне нужно написать класс-итератор перебирающий элементы списка при вызове оператора ++, для которого определены операторы * и →;

Comment: Как звучит вопрос? В чём возникли затруднения?

Comment: Есть класс для двусвязного списка, у которого есть указатель на голову и на хвост, каждый элемент указывает на предыдущий и следующий, надо написать класс-итератор, который будет перебирать элементы списка

Comment: "У меня есть класс" - ну да, у вас есть класс, но его никто больше кроме вас не видит.  "надо написать класс-итератор" - да нужно, полезная штука, вы начали его писать, но возникли затруднения. В чём они заключаются? Кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/717528/edit) дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Для двусвязного списка вы можете реализовать [двунаправленный итератор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/).

---

**1)** Нужен конструктор по умолчанию, копирующий конструктор и копирующий оператор присваивания.

> Is default-constructible, copy-constructible, copy-assignable and
>   destructible

```
X a;
X b(a);
b = a;
```

---

**2)** Должны быть определены операторы `==` и `!=`

> Can be compared for equivalence using the equality/inequality
>   operators (meaningful when both iterator values iterate over the same
>   underlying sequence).

```
a == b
a != b
```

---

**3)** Должны быть определены операторы `*` и `->`

> Can be dereferenced as an rvalue (if in a dereferenceable state).

```
*a
a->m
```

---

**4)** Для неконстантных итераторов должен быть определен оператор `*`, который возвращает lvalue. Ссылку, например

> For mutable iterators (non-constant iterators): Can be dereferenced as
>   an lvalue (if in a dereferenceable state).

```
*a = t
```

---

**5)** Нужны постфиксный и префиксный операторы `++`

> Can be incremented (if in a dereferenceable state). The result is
>   either also dereferenceable or a past-the-end iterator. Two iterators
>   that compare equal, keep comparing equal after being both increased.

```
++a 
a++
*a++
```

---

**6)** Нужны постфиксный и префиксный операторы `--`

> Can be decremented (if a dereferenceable iterator value precedes it).

```
--a
a--
*a--
```

---

Таким образом, объявление вашего итератора будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
template<class T>
class List{
public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>{
    public:
        iterator();
        iterator(const iterator &other);
        iterator& operator=(const iterator &other);
        T &operator*() const;
        T *operator->() const;
        bool operator==(const iterator &other) const;
        bool operator!=(const iterator &o) const;
        iterator &operator++();
        iterator operator++(int);
        iterator &operator--();
        iterator operator--(int);
    };
};
```

Если что, можно [подсмотреть](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h#L162) как реализуют итератор другие люди